# hide and show div elements by size of window

Tags: jquery, ios

I have a bit of code for hiding a div based on the width of the browser window. It works great within a browser window. When I try to open the same page within a twitter iOS app, the code no longer works. Here is the code.

```
$(function () {
    var isAdded = false;
    $(window).resize(function () {
        if ($(window).width() > 975) {
             isAdded = true;
             $('.sideBar').removeClass('hidden');
        } else if ($(window).width() < 975) {
            isAdded = false;
             $('.sideBar').addClass('hidden');
        }
    });
});
```

If I add `alert(screen.width);`to the second condition, the alert window does not show up in the mobile device. Any help is appreciated

**UPDATE**
I took  Sphinxxx's response and tried this. It works but seems a little sloppy. What do you all think? I am a little green with js/jquery

```
$(function () {
    var isAdded = false;
    $(window).load(function () {
        if ($(window).width() < 975) {
            isAdded = false;
            $('.sideBar').addClass('hidden');
        };
        $(window).resize(function () {
            if ($(window).width() > 975) {
                 isAdded = true;
                 $('.sideBar').removeClass('hidden');
            } else if ($(window).width() < 975) {
                isAdded = false;
                 $('.sideBar').addClass('hidden');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Does the iOS app ever actually get *resized*? Try using the `load` event instead: `$(window).load(function() {`.

Comment: This actually worked but the way I did it may seem a little sloppy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using `meta` in `<head>`?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

**UPD:**
Try to replace your wrapper function with `.ready()` function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var isAdded = false;

    $(window).resize(function () {
        if ($(window).width() > 975) {
            isAdded = true;
            $('.sideBar').removeClass('hidden');

        } else if ($(window).width() < 975) {
            isAdded = false;
            $('.sideBar').addClass('hidden');
        }
    });

    $(window).resize(); // don't forget to trigger a code
});
```

Comment: And you tried to resize? If you want it to apply the cody after page load you should fire this event. Updated my anwer.

Answer (score 0):

A fairly clean way to do it would be to put the adjustment code in a separate function, and then have both `load` and `resize` call that function:

```
$(function () {
    var win = $(window),
        side = $('.sideBar'),
        isAdded = false;

    function rearrange() {
        if (win.width() > 975) {
            isAdded = true;
            side.removeClass('hidden');
        } else {
            isAdded = false;
            side.addClass('hidden');
        }
    }

    win.load(rearrange);
    win.resize(rearrange);
});
```